# Yii CDbCriteria: how to get value from "3rd" table with AR?

Tags: yii

I have tables: driver, driver_negotiation, base_negotiation and team

In DriverController model I want to get the team_id (which is located in base_negotiation) that the driver is negotiating with.

In Driver model I have:

```
'driverNegotiation' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'DriverNegotiation', 'driver_id')
```

And in DriverNegotiation:

```
'baseNegotiation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BaseNegotiation', 'base_negotiation_id')
```

In DriverController I am building something like:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
    'condition' => 'baseNegotiation.team_id=13',
    'with' => 'driverNegotiation',
    'together' => true,

));
```

But I get:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'baseNegotiation.team_id' in 'where clause'. 
The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `driver` `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `driver_negotiation` `driverNegotiation` ON 
(`driverNegotiation`.`driver_id`=`t`.`id`) WHERE (baseNegotiation.team_id=13)
```

So I can get everything from the driver_nagotiation table, but nothing from one table further.

Do I need to use join to get the correct stuff or is there a better way?

Comment: `'with' => 'driverNegotiation.baseNegotiation'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'with' => 'driverNegotiation.baseNegotiation'
```

This did the trick.